# is there a way to find which condition in an if statement failed in powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have multiple checks in an if condition and if any one of them fails status should be failed. For this what I have now is multiple if statements comparing each value to something so that script can notify what exactly failed. Is there a way that I can put these condition in an and criteria in if statement and determine which match failed

```
if ($a -eq "apple")
{
    Write-Host "My fruit is apple"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "My fruit is not apple"
}
if ($b -eq "banana")
{
    Write-Host "My fruit is banana"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "My fruit is not banana"
}
```

If I want to minimize if statements I can write

```
if (($b -eq "banana") -and ($a -eq "apple"))
{
    Write-Host "My fruit is banana and apple"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Match failed for $a or $b"
}
```

In this if $b is banana but $a is not apple it will enter else part but how do I tell it $a that does not match. I need to know only criteria that is not satisfied

Comment: Can any of your variables be any of a collection of fruits?  Or does each variable need to correspond to its specific fruit?

Answer (score 3):

A bitmask for fruit options should work nicely. An example is like so,

```
# Fruit values are such that each will toggle its own bits.
[flags()] Enum Fruits {
  Apple  = 0x01
  Banana = 0x02
  Pear   = 0x04
  Orange = 0x08
  Pomelo = 0x10
  Melon  = 0x20
}

# Add some fruits into a basket    
$basket = [fruits]'apple'+[fruits]'banana'

# Check contents    
[fruits].GetEnumNames() | % {
    "$_ in basket? " $basket.HasFlag([fruits]::$_)
}
Apple in basket?  True
Banana in basket?  False
Pear in basket?  True
Orange in basket?  False
Pomelo in basket?  False
Melon in basket?  False

# Fill basket with sum of fruits:    
$basket = [fruits]17

[fruits].GetEnumNames() | % {
    "$_ in basket? " $basket.HasFlag([fruits]::$_)
}
Apple in basket?  True
Banana in basket?  False
Pear in basket?  False
Orange in basket?  False
Pomelo in basket?  True
Melon in basket?  False

# Remove an apple
$basket -= [fruits]'apple'
$basket
Pomelo
```

`$basket.value__` will be greater than zero if there are any fruits.

More discussion is provided in [two](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/managing-bit-flags-part-1) [articles](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/managing-bit-flags-part-4).

Comment: Note: requires powershell v5+.  Nice use of an `enum`, I had no idea a `flags` attribute existed.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Indeed. While little-known, it _is_ documented in [about_Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum).

Answer (score 1):

Given that your values are represented in distinct variables `$a` and `$b` (conceptually, an *array* of values), a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) is your best bet:

```
# Sample values that are valid
$a = 'banana'
$b = 'apple'

# Collect the values to check in an array.
# (You could pass `$a, $b` directly to `switch` as well.)
$valuesToCheck = $a, $b

switch ($valuesToCheck) {
  'apple'  { 'My fruit is an apple.'; continue }
  'banana' { 'My fruit is a banana.'; continue }
  default  { Write-Warning "'$_' is not a known fruit." } 
}
```

The above yields:

```
My fruit is a banana.
My fruit is an apple.
```

If you changed `$b`, for instance, to an invalid value, e.g., `$b = 'spinach'`, you'd get:

```
My fruit is a banana.
WARNING: 'spinach' is not a known fruit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use hash tables?

Look at this article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7064dc22-0611-4f4c-a846-dc24ed344389/comparing-hashtables?forum=winserverpowershell

Create two hash tables and compare them.
You can add more keys and values without changing the code.

Hash1 will be your template with all correct values and Hash2 you use all the values that you want to check.

```
$Results = @()
$hash1 = @{"test1"="123";"test2"="abcd";"test3"="xyz"}
$hash2 = @{"test1"="123";"test2"="cdey";"test3"="xyz";"test4"="pdqy"}
$hash1.keys | %{
    if ($hash2.keys -match $_){
        if (!($hash2.$_ -match $hash1.$_)) {
            $Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="Hash1";Key=$_;Value=$hash1.$_}
        }
    } Else {$Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="Hash1";Key=$_;Value=$hash1.$_}}
}
$hash2.keys | %{
    if ($hash1.keys -match $_){
        if (!($hash1.$_ -match $hash2.$_)) {
            $Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="Hash2";Key=$_;Value=$hash2.$_}
        }
    } Else {$Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="Hash2";Key=$_;Value=$hash2.$_}}
}
$Results | select Hash,Key,Value | sort -property Key,Hash | FT
```

Simple explanation about how hash tables works in powershell
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/powershell_hashtables.htm